# XMLHTTPRequest doesn't worked with Cordova apps

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I build and I emulate a test version of futur application. 
But I have a problem and I found different solution on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me.

I found the first solution to remove and re-install `cordova-plugin-whitelist` and after that put this `<allow-navigation href="*" />`

If you have an idea you saved my day.
EDIT : I run nothing server for example on webapp `localhost:8000` probably the problem is here ?

Comment: Can you post your Javascript code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I solved the problem during the day